# Is it possible to change a google cloud function from Ubuntu 22 (default image) to Ubuntu 18?

Tags: firebase, ffmpeg, google-cloud-functions

I created a google cloud function via the Firebase CLI. I wasn't initially aware of which runtime environment the function (2nd generation) I created would be running on, however, I noticed that it didn't have `ffmpeg` installed so I tried looking for the actual runtime env. I then encountered this: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/system-packages#requesting_a_package and through additional searches understood that the default base image is now ubuntu 22 which doesn't have `ffmpeg` -> so I tried checking if I could switch back to Ubuntu 18 (I haven't figured out how, or if it's possible at all). Is it possible to switch images or at least installing ffmpeg in the runtime I'm using?

Comment: Why don't you just bundle ffmpeg that you build yourself into your deployment?  Either that, or build an image yourself and run it on Cloud Run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the server images used for deployment.  When you target a version of node, you are getting that one image provided for that version.

If you want control over the image, you should use a different product, such as Cloud Run, where you can build your own docker image.

BTW the presence of ffmpeg isn't based on the version of ubuntu.  It's an optional package that needs to be installed explicitly.  For example: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-ubuntu-20-04/

Comment: With Node 16 being deprecated soon, this gets more relevant now. Is there a good solution for "ordinary" Cloud Functions users (Firebase) that doesn't require running a custom image on Cloud Run?

When adding the ffmpeg binaries to the functions folder, the deployment build is almost 90MB larger, takes ages, and fails often...